# Laravel ShouldBeUnique doesn't make jobs to be unique

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I expected job marked with `ShouldBeUnique` interface to not be dispatched more than once. However all jobs are dispatched like usually.

In my .env file redis is set to be used for queue connection as well as cache driver:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

I have two queue workers running, which compete for jobs from queue.

To push jobs there's console command:

```php
class TestUnique extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'test:unique';
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    private Dispatcher $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SomeJob(1));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SomeJob(2));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SomeJob(3));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SomeJob(4));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new SomeJob(5));

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Job class looks like this (note that `uniqueId` is the same):

```php
final class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    public function __construct(private int $id) { }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        var_dump("start handle $this->id");
        sleep(5);
        var_dump("finish handle $this->id");
    }

    public $uniqueFor = 3600;

    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Once we run console command to dispatch jobs, all of them are dispatched like usually without `ShouldBeUnique`. Logs:

```
queue_worker_2       | [2021-10-04 08:07:44][p0j7QmQt7JNFEWUoxdaEOuheJiPFTYrh] Processing: App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_2       | string(14) "start handle 1"
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:44][DxFLi5V1UC7HfzpDFMmwv6po3Mh7Weap] Processing: App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | string(14) "start handle 2"
queue_worker_2       | string(15) "finish handle 1"
queue_worker_2       | [2021-10-04 08:07:49][p0j7QmQt7JNFEWUoxdaEOuheJiPFTYrh] Processed:  App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | string(15) "finish handle 2"
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:49][DxFLi5V1UC7HfzpDFMmwv6po3Mh7Weap] Processed:  App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:49][6sZoEH3WMsCMxYAmupy5RezlQezaAYag] Processing: App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | string(14) "start handle 3"
queue_worker_2       | [2021-10-04 08:07:49][jQQNCm6MrsyxkxSClDsBNIfQezQIfBV1] Processing: App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_2       | string(14) "start handle 4"
queue_worker_1       | string(15) "finish handle 3"
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:54][6sZoEH3WMsCMxYAmupy5RezlQezaAYag] Processed:  App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_2       | string(15) "finish handle 4"
queue_worker_2       | [2021-10-04 08:07:54][jQQNCm6MrsyxkxSClDsBNIfQezQIfBV1] Processed:  App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:54][iGt3kbZTqj6lrXgm0SFFcaqVjbQ5tUqs] Processing: App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
queue_worker_1       | string(14) "start handle 5"
queue_worker_1       | string(15) "finish handle 5"
queue_worker_1       | [2021-10-04 08:07:59][iGt3kbZTqj6lrXgm0SFFcaqVjbQ5tUqs] Processed:  App\Console\Commands\SomeJob
```

This is not matter of cached code, because service definition uses `queue:listen`:

```yaml
queue_worker:
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_php
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: php artisan queue:listen
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes: *php-volumes
    environment: *php-env
    networks:
        - main_network
    depends_on:
        - php
```

Can anyone tell what is `ShouldBeUnique` is intended for and what is wrong with current code?

Comment: What cache driver are you using?

Comment: use "php artisan queue:restart" and dispatch again

Comment: redis is cache driver, restart won't help as `queue:listen` is used

Comment: since you are running in containers (I assume) does each container have its own redis service or is it shared?

Comment: There's only one redis container, which is used

Comment: What I found is that problem appears only when code uses `\Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher` to dispatch jobs. Therefore if I were using `dispatch()` function problem won't appear, however generally it is not recommended as it brings implicit dependency into code.

Comment: Yes, actually it uses PendingDispatch which will dispatch anything in `__destruct` method.